# Electromagnetic Theory

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetostatics

As, using the fact that E*A stays constant for a point charge  ( E= electric field, A=area of sphere centered on charge touching the point where we have to measure E) , we can prove that E falls by 1/r^2 . Is there any basic method for the Magnetic field?

Comment: Magnetic field of what? Of a moving point charge, or of some other geometric object? The former is more difficult to solve for than the latter in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

The calculation you describe is based on spherical symmetry. That is, for a point charge the field lines radiate outwards equally in all directions. However there are no magnetic charges (as far as we know) so there is no analagous situation for a magnetic field.

The simplest [magnetic field is a dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole), and this doesn't have a nice simple variation with distance like $1/r^2$ though it varies approximately as $1/r^3$. There is [an analogous electric dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_dipole_moment) as well, and this shows the same variation with distance as the magnetic dipole.

Comment: I would argue that the canonical example and simplest magnetic field is that of an infinitely long wire with uniform current. While this example has no spherical symmetry, it does enjoy radial symmetry about the wire. Moreover, it has a nice variation as $1/r$.

Comment: @Nathan but clearly, this would correspond to the electrostatic problem of calculating the electric field due to an infinite wire with uniform charge density.

Answer (score 1):

To answer whether there is a magnetic analog to the point charge of an electric field, it may be helpful to review the exact reason why the electric field of a point charge yields a simple analytical result. The primary equation of electrostatics, [Gauss's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss's_law), states that the flux of the electric field $\textbf{E}$ through *any* closed surface $S$ is proportional to the net charge $Q_{enc}$ enclosed within the surface. We can state this mathematically as,

$$
\oint_S \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{A} = \frac{Q_{enc}}{\epsilon_0},
$$

where $\epsilon_0$ is the [permittivity of free space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_permittivity). If we consider a point charge located at the origin, we conclude that the spherical symmetry of the stationary point charge implies that there is a spherically symmetric electric field. If we take $S$ to be a sphere of surface area $A = 4 \pi r^2$, we notice that the electric field is radial and constant along the sphere, so

$$
\oint_S \textbf{E} \cdot d\textbf{A} = EA.
$$

From this it quickly follows that $E \propto 1/r^2$, since the right hand side of Gauss's law (the charge enclosed) is constant. Now let's attempt to construct an analogous situation in magnetostatics. We should use the same logic if we wish to find a mathematically similar answer. One of the most important laws in magnetostatics is Ampère's law, which states that

$$
\oint_\gamma \textbf{B} \cdot d\textbf{r} = \mu_0 I_{enc},
$$

where $\textbf{B}$ is the magnetic field, $\gamma$ is a closed curve, and $I_{enc}$ is the current enclosed within the curve. Since we are now talking about curves instead of surfaces, it makes sense to consider a circle of length $L = 2 \pi r$ instead of a spherical surface (note: a circle is also $S^1$, a one dimensional sphere). Instead of spherical symmetry, we now require cylindrical symmetry since a circle is *cylindrically symmetric* in three dimensions. The canonical example is to consider a wire of infinite length with a uniform current constant in time. Since the wire enjoys cylindrical symmetry, we can deduce that the magnetic field "curls" around the wire (tangent to every point on a circular curve).

[image]

We then apply the same logic that we did in the point charge example to arrive at

$$
\oint_\gamma \textbf{B} \cdot d\textbf{r} = BL.
$$

Since $L = 2 \pi r$ and $I_{enc} = constant$, we have $B \propto 1/r$ and the analogy is complete$^1$.

---

1. The exact magnetic field is given by $\textbf{B}(\textbf{r}) = \frac{\mu_0 I}{  2 \pi r }\hat{\theta}$